# Why do resource files need to be minified?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I've been looking at ways to improve perfomance of my website. I've seen many people mentioning that it is good to minify files in production, which would improve speed as the amount of data that needs to be transferred would reduce. To my understanding, most modern browsers cache HTML, CSS and JS files. If that is the case, is there any additional benefit of minifying these files?

Comment: and what about the **first** and most important time ! if the first time the website is slow, i will leave

Comment: Please think about visitors on mobile devices with slow connections.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understand that one - but is that the only benefit?

Comment: it's not enough ? :) ... did you hear about bounce rate ? if not then read about it

Comment: @A.L Wouldn't mobile browsers cache the pages once they have been visited?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not in my application.

Comment: so it's clear that you are not developing for other people but only for your self ;) in this case you don't even need any optimization as am sure  you will wait for your application to load

Comment: You might also want to enable HTTP compression.

Answer (score 3):

> "To my understanding, most modern browsers cache HTML, CSS and JS files"

True, but cached resources are available only **after the first visit**. The first visit to your website will result in the client downloading all of these resources, and only then caching them, which could result in high response times for large files.

Resource file minification has no other real benifit besides reducing loading time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Currently, none of the files are minified in my application. If the improvements are for the first load alone, then minfying the files are not worth the trouble.

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanPrakash Happy to help. Good luck with your app.